# FLUTTER - Reduce the quality of network image coming from http request so that it can load faster

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I'm trying to fetch images through an http request and ends up getting an image with a high resolution which sometimes is not loading if the internet connection is poor.

Is there any package/plugin available which can reduce the quality of an image that is coming from an http request?

```
Image.network(
  "${widget.jsonData["articles"][index]["urlToImage"]}",
    fit: BoxFit.fill,
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

it's better if you use [cache_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) :

```
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/200x150",
  imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
          image: imageProvider,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          colorFilter:
              ColorFilter.mode(Colors.red, BlendMode.colorBurn)),
    ),
  ),
  placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

The quality of the image is determined from the image file format. If it is a Jpeg or PNG image it can be saved as "progressive" (aka interlaced) and saved as such on the backend.

Baseline JPEG loads all of the image in one step.
Progressive (interlaced) JPEG is suitable for large images where a blurred image is shown upon initial loading of the file, and as the file is loaded, more details are made visible.

You can convert the images with an editor such as IrfanView.

[image: Save Jpeg as progressive]

I don't believe you can do anything on the client side to control this behavior.